Connect Swift's SwiftStomp and Spring Boot
I'm facing issues establishing a STOMP connection between my Swift client and Spring Boot. In Swift, I'm using the SwiftStomp library to handle STOMP communication. The problem arises when I try to send a message to a specific user — Spring successfully sends the message, but it doesn’t reach the Swift client. However, when I send a message from Spring to a general topic, it works perfectly. My goal is to be able to send messages to individual users.
Swift
class MultiplayerViewModel: ObservableObject {
        
    private var socketClient: SwiftStomp?
    
    let socketURL = URL(string: "ws://localhost:8091/ws")!
        
    
    func connect() {
        self.socketClient = SwiftStomp(host: socketURL)
        self.socketClient?.delegate = self
        self.socketClient?.autoReconnect = true

        socketClient?.connect()
    }
    
    func disconnect() {
        socketClient?.disconnect()
    }
}

extension MultiplayerViewModel: SwiftStompDelegate {
    
    func onConnect(swiftStomp: SwiftStomp, connectType: StompConnectType) {
        print("Stomp Client Connected: \(connectType)")
        
        socketClient?.subscribe(to: "/user/queue/greetings", mode: .clientIndividual)

        socketClient?.send(body: "lol", to: "/app/greetings")
    }
    
    func onDisconnect(swiftStomp: SwiftStomp, disconnectType: StompDisconnectType) {
        print("Stomp Client Disconnected: \(disconnectType)")
    }
    
    func onError(swiftStomp : SwiftStomp, briefDescription : String, fullDescription : String?, receiptId : String?, type : StompErrorType) {
        print("Error: \(briefDescription)")
    }
    
    func onMessageReceived(swiftStomp: SwiftStomp, message: Any?, messageId: String, destination: String, headers : [String : String]) {
        print("Received message from destination: \(message)")
        
    }
    
    func onReceipt(swiftStomp : SwiftStomp, receiptId : String) {
        
    }
}

Spring Boot
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/user");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
    }
}

@Controller
public class StompController {

    @MessageMapping("/greetings")
    @SendToUser("/queue/greetings")
    public String reply(@Payload String message) {
        return  "Hello " + message;
    }
}


Here is the logs from Spring:
2024-09-15T19:34:51.321+03:00 DEBUG 67961 --- [nio-8091-exec-5] o.s.w.s.s.s.WebSocketHttpRequestHandler  : GET /ws
2024-09-15T19:34:51.439+03:00 DEBUG 67961 --- [nio-8091-exec-5] s.w.s.h.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator : New StandardWebSocketSession[id=43304528-2cb0-e7c3-cfb5-12f770d36b71, uri=ws://localhost:8091/ws]
2024-09-15T19:34:55.620+03:00 DEBUG 67961 --- [nboundChannel-2] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Processing CONNECT session=43304528-2cb0-e7c3-cfb5-12f770d36b71
2024-09-15T19:34:56.412+03:00 DEBUG 67961 --- [nboundChannel-5] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Processing SUBSCRIBE /user/queue/greetings id=/user/queue/greetings session=43304528-2cb0-e7c3-cfb5-12f770d36b71
2024-09-15T19:34:56.416+03:00 DEBUG 67961 --- [nboundChannel-7] .WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler : Searching methods to handle SEND /app/greetings session=43304528-2cb0-e7c3-cfb5-12f770d36b71 text/plain payload=lol, lookupDestination='/greetings'
2024-09-15T19:34:56.421+03:00 DEBUG 67961 --- [nboundChannel-7] .WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler : Invoking StompController#reply[2 args]
2024-09-15T19:34:56.427+03:00 DEBUG 67961 --- [nboundChannel-7] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Processing MESSAGE destination=/user/43304528-2cb0-e7c3-cfb5-12f770d36b71/queue/greetings session=43304528-2cb0-e7c3-cfb5-12f770d36b71 payload=Hello lol


